# Zookeeper does not start normally (Established session 0x10000025c8a0001 with negotiated timeout 6000 )and kafka fails

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I had  previously run zookeeper and kafka successfully many times, and I believe my installation and configurations are correct.

The only change I made was to the zookeeper config file:

```
dataDir=/Users/garynackenson/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/data/zookeeper
```

which I have created the directory for.

Now when I run zookeeper instead of getting info binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181

I  get the error below, and kafka fails with a port 9092 in use error (i have restarted my machine and checked every way i know to see that port 9092 is not in use

the last message from zoopkeeper below, which does not look right

```
 INFO Established session 0x10000025c8a0001 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /127.0.0.1:49977 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

When zookeeper starts that way  kafka fails with a 9092 in use error (see below) – I restarted and checked that I am not using port 9092.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:9092: Address already in use.
```

A little while later , I saw that zookeeper had a different issue:

```
INFO Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49986 which had sessionid 0x100000b679d0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

I ran zookeeper again and saw the more ‘normal’ binding to 2081 4 messages up

```
[2018-10-03 18:25:08,064] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

[2018-10-03 18:25:09,055] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:50014 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

[2018-10-03 18:25:09,062] INFO Client attempting to renew session 0x10000025c8a0001 at /127.0.0.1:50014 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)

[2018-10-03 18:25:09,066] INFO Established session 0x10000025c8a0001 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /127.0.0.1:50014 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

but kafka is still failing every time

also sometimes i get the following message when i start zookeeper

```
[2018-10-03 18:10:36,097] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10000025c8a0001 type:delete cxid:0x47 zxid:0x179 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Comment: How did you check whether another process was listening on port 9092?

Comment: Also, are you running a multi-broker setup?